# repeat setselectedindex function to select same value in multiple dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

After selecting the set value from the first dropdown menu, how can I make the below function move to the next dropdown menu and select the same value?

```
var size = "4";
function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++ ) {
        if ( s.options[i].text == v ) {
            s.options[i].selected = true; 
            return; 
        }
    }
}
setSelectedIndex(document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0],size);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `onchange="setSelected(this.value)"` attribute to where you create your dropdowns. Then in your function you try passing the index of the selected item to the other dropdowns.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Quite new to this. Do I have to incorporate your suggestion as follows:    var size = "4";
function setSelectedIndex(s, v) {
for ( var i = 0; i < s.options.length; i++ ) { if ( s.options[i].text == v ) { s.selectedIndex = 4; //The index you want to be selected 
   break; } } } setSelectedIndex(document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0],size);

Comment: Yes just try replacing your `if` block with mine but set the index number to what you desire. And I'd like to know something... is the size really a string or that was just a typo?

Comment: Thanks. Tried replacing but doesn't work... Size is a string. Have multiple dropdown menus with size numbers. My function selects the size (in this case 4) in the first dropdown menu but doesn't select the same size in the next following dropdown menu. Hope this is clear...

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope its not too complicated for you

Comment: Applying my function to dropdowns that are not created by me. It correctly selects the size (in my case "4") in the first dropdown but doesn't select the same size in the next dropdown... Is there a way for the function to "move" to the next dropdown and repeat the same selection process?